# Pass Bash flags and commands

Tags: bash

I'd like to be able to run flags and commands something like:

```
bash script.sh -c flag1 -b flag2 command1 command2
```

Some more real examples:

```
e.g.1 bash oneScript.sh -p password -u user list images
e.g.2 bash oneScript.sh -u user list images (ask for password while running the script) ...
e.g.3 bash oneScript.sh -p password delete files (ask for user while running the script) ... another command, not listing but deleting)
```

How can I do something like this in bash scripts?
I'd like to be able to add some extra flags (or not) if the user wants but after the flags I'd like to add some commands that can be read in the script

Any idea please?

Regards,

Comment: Have you looked into the `getopts` builtin?

Comment: Yes ... but this is not enough

Answer (score 1):

I think I founded an answer:

While I'll have flags like:

```
# Way to force the branch version
seed="true" # set default to true
while getopts 'bc:hp:o:s:t:u:v:' flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
        b) backup="true" ;;
        c) configFile="${OPTARG}" ;;
        h) export helpMenu="true" ;;
        p) rootPassword="${OPTARG}" ;;
        s) seed="${OPTARG}" ;;
        t) restoreTag="${OPTARG}" ;;
        u) upgradeTo="${OPTARG}" ;;
        v) versionNumber="${OPTARG}" ;;
        *) echo "blabla" ;;
    esac
done
```

I can also have something like this:

```
args=("$@")
ELEMENTS=${#args[@]}
_option=""
_command=""
for (( i=0;i<$ELEMENTS;i++)); do 
    if [[ "${args[${i}]}" == "restore" || "${args[${i}]}" == "list" || "${args[${i}]}" == "backup" ]]; then
        _option="${args[${i}]}"
        value=$((i+1))
        _command=${args[${value}]}
    fi
done
```

So ... now I should be able to do:

```
bash script.sh -p password -t 0 list images
```

Comment: Good stuff, seems like you have solved your own problem! Be sure to accept your answer (unless someone posts something better). You have to wait ~48 hrs to accept. BUT ... if you're testing `"${args[${i}]}"` each time in the mile-wide `if ` test, you already know about `case`, it seems that it the easier to read solution. But maybe there is something there I'm missing. You know your problem better than I do ;-) Good luck.

Comment: I think you could use the `$OPTIND` parameter to shift your flags away after you've processed them instead of re-building your non-option arguments array, see [this example](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts).